# Homebrew dnsmasq "Service exited with abnormal code: 2" (Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6)

Tags: homebrew, launchd, dns

**Workaround** *(update)*

A quick workaround is to stop the job through `brew services stop dnsmasq`. Then you should first unload the `launchd` configuration file and then reload it.

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
```

I found this solution in this article [Brew install dnsmasq in macOS Sierra](https://medium.com/@narakuw/brew-install-dnsmasq-in-macos-sierra-26021c824be8).

Now you can test `dnsmasq` response both with `dig` and `dscacheutil`.

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name fullpipeumbrella.loc
name: fullpipeumbrella.loc
ipv6_address: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
ipv6_address: fe80:1::1

name: fullpipeumbrella.loc
ip_address: 127.0.0.1

$ dig @127.0.0.1 fullpipeumbrella.loc

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @127.0.0.1 fullpipeumbrella.loc
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10930
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fullpipeumbrella.loc.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fullpipeumbrella.loc.   0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 16:56:38 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

Anyway this should be considered an hack (at least this is my guess), in fact: first of all, there is `brew services` utility and the software is supposed to be launched by it; second, `launchctl` man page states clearly that `load` and `unload` subcommands are legacy commands. They are still there though from many years. We don't know when Apple will decide to deprecate them and what to give as a replacement.

```
Subcommands from the previous implementation of launchd are generally
available, though some may be unimplemented. Unimplemented subcommands
are documented as such.

load | unload [-wF] [-S sessiontype] [-D searchpath] paths ...
```

Another hack to launch the dnsmasq job can be this one (taken from [Using Dnsmasq for local development on OS X](https://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/)).

```
sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
```

Though `start` and `stop` subcommands are described as development test commands and not production commands and they are legacy subcommands too.

```
start label
         Start the specified job by label. The expected use of this sub-
         command is for debugging and testing so that one can manually
         kick-start an on-demand server.

stop label
         Stop the specified job by label. If a job is on-demand, launchd
         may immediately restart the job if launchd finds any criteria
         that is satisfied.
```

**The Problem**

I installed `dnsmasq` through Homebrew. Unfortunately it constantly crash and is resumed by `launchd` through `brew services` launch script.

This is the log:

```
Jun 11 10:45:33 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq[48386]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
Jun 11 10:45:33 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

I set it up following some tutorials, this is my settings.

```
#/private/etc/Hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

# [...]

127.0.0.1               local.web
0:0:0:0:0:ffff:7f00:1   local.web
fe80::1%lo0             local.web
127.0.0.1               fullpipeumbrella.loc
0:0:0:0:0:ffff:7f00:1   fullpipeumbrella.loc
fe80::1%lo0             fullpipeumbrella.loc

# [...]

127.0.0.1               localhost.demo1.com
0:0:0:0:0:ffff:7f00:1   localhost.demo1.com
fe80::1%lo0             localhost.demo1.com

#/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf

domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=208.67.220.220
```

This is the output of `brew services list`:

```
$ brew services list
Name    Status  User     Plist
dnsmasq started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
httpd   stopped          
php     started username /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@7.1 stopped          
php@7.2 stopped
```

And the output of `ps`, `$ ps -e | grep -v grep | grep dnsmasq`:

```
   65 ??         0:02.31 /usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/sbin/dnsmasq --keep-in-foreground -C /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

Finally I made a test with `dscacheutil`:

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name fullpipeumbrella.loc
name: fullpipeumbrella.loc
ipv6_address: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
ipv6_address: fe80:1::1

name: fullpipeumbrella.loc
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

Thanks in advance... :-)

Comment: I've faced the same issue today, did you find any solution?

Comment: ok, so I figured out, without sudo `dnsmasq` can't use port 53, and if you change port value in `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`everything starts working. the port value must be in range from 1024 to 10000